# Multiple objects in async pipeline

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, pipeline

I'm building a pipeline (with nodeJS) and I came across a case I don't know how best to solve:

The pipeline:

`collect` => `clean` => `merge`

`collect` will fetch many resources and when done pass it to `clean`. The problem is that the output of `collect` is a list, but the input of `clean` is a single item.

The point is that `clean` doesn't need to know we handle a list of items, it only needs to clean one single item and return it. Also the full list of items will get very big, so the simple solution of iterating them in `clean` is not even doable.

Can anyone point to a design pattern for this case ?

Comment: I think you could use Node.js streams for this. This would be good if data comes out of collect portion by portion. OR you could use RabbitMQ or other queue for this. If you provide some code it would be easier to find the proper solution.

Comment: I keep coming back to streams as well, I'll investigate more. In the meantime I came up with a "decorator" concept: https://github.com/lipsumar/promise-pipeline/blob/master/index.js

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you need is map/reduce. Promise libraries, as well as `async` provide methods for map/reduce. The example below uses bluebird promises. The functions use bluebird.resolve to turn results into promises, in your case you would have some asynchronous function calls that returned promises. In this example "cleaning" is just slicing a string, and merging is combining the result in an object.

```
'use strict';
const bluebird = require('bluebird');
const collection = ['foo', 'bar'];
const clean = (item) => {
   return bluebird.resolve(item.slice(0, 2));
}

const merge = (merged, item, index) => {
   merged[index] = item;
   return bluebird.resolve(merged);
};

bluebird.map(collection, clean).reduce(merge, {}).then((result) => {
   console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
   // {"0":"fo","1":"ba"}
});
```